# como hago para que el campo de un registro coincida con el value de un SELECT OPTION en php

Tags: php, jquery, html5, sql-server

quiero hacer una actualización de los datos personales de un usuario ya logueado, yo tengo una tabla llamada persona en esta tabla se encuentran los registros ya existentes que quiero actualizar, en esta misma tabla tengo campos como; IdEstadoCivil, IdSexo, LugarNacimiento y estos campos almacenan solo el ID del nombre de elemento que almacena.

**¿Que puedo hacer para que los id que guardan estos campos coincidan con los elementos que tiene mi SELECT OPTION dependiendo del id que tenga almacenado?**

Esto es un formulario de actualización y en caso de que el usuario quiera cambiarlo por cualquiera de los elementos que ofrece los option pues que capture el valor que contiene.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que lo quieras hacer con jQuery, la opción *más fácil*:

```js
$('#estadoCivil').val(40);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                        <select id="estadoCivil" name="estadoCivil">
                            <option value="0">--Selecciona--</option>
                            <option value="40">Soltero(a)</option>
                            <option value="41">Casado(a)</option>
                            <option value="42">Divorciado(a)</option>
                            <option value="43">Viudo(a)</option>
                            <option value="44">Unión libre</option>
                        </select>
```

Al final de tu php tendrías que poner algo como:

```
<script>
$('#estadoCivil').val(<?php echo $row['idEstadoCivil'];?>);
</script>
```

Pero vas a tener que hacerlo por cada *select* y ¿qué pasa si algo falla en javascript o el usuario no lo tiene activo? Va a dejar de funcionar todo.

Lo mejor es crear cada *select* con base en un origen de datos y analizar el valor al generar los *option* para saber si debe estar seleccionado o no:

```
// Origen de datos para estado civil
$edoCivil = [
    0 => '-- Selecciona --',
    40 => 'Soltero(a)',
    41 => 'Casado(a)',
    42 => 'Divorciado(a)',
    43 => 'Viudo(a)',
    44 => 'Unión libre'
];

// Función para generar select
function html_select($nombre, $id, $valor, $origen) {
    // Iniciar etiqueta
    echo "<select name=\"$nombre\" id=\"$id\">\n";
    // Recorrer origen de datos para generar opciones
    foreach($origen as $clave => $texto) {
        // La clave es igual al valor? Debe estar seleccionado
        $sel = ($valor == $clave) ? ' selected' : '';
        // Crear opción
        echo "<option value=\"$clave\"$sel>$texto</option>\n";
    }
    // Cerrar etiqueta
    echo "</select>\n";
}
// Crear select para estado civil
html_select('estadoCivil', 'estadoCivil', $row['idEstadoCivil'], $edoCivil);
```

Por supuesto, esta función te va a servir para mostrar todos los *select*, solo tienes que crear el origen de datos para cada uno y enviar los parámetros adecuados.